# virtualenv: command not found in Python

Tags: python, path, virtualenv

I am trying to create a new virtual environment for a tutorial. I have installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` multiple times but every time I try creating a new virtual environment my terminal displays - `mkvirtualenv: command not found`. When I try finding out the version of `virtualenv` it shows `virtualenv: command not found`. Something similar was happening with my pip installation as well but then it got resolved when I used some command.

I would like to point out that my `PATH` seems to be really messed up. The PATH is pointing to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`. Please help.

I saw something else when I use `pip show virtualenv` it gives me details of the version and the author but when I use `virtualenv --version` it sends a `virtualenv: command not found`.

Comment: pip install virtualenv

Comment: It’s most likely that it’s not installed in your python path

Comment: @DenisTsoi so this worked for me -  `python -m virtualenv venv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you will need to install `virtualenv` as it is a python 2 external dependency.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

this will allow you to use virtualenv globally.

Alternatively, you can use from Python 3.5+

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

However if you dont wish to support python 2 you can use venv which is installed on from python 3.3

```
python3 -v venv venv
```

Answer (score 2):

Took quite some time to figure it out but what worked for me was to install it using pip3 install instead of pip install

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```